# Cyclic definition of NP-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, np-complete, np-hard

Trying to understand the concept of NP-completeness, I came across this pearl on Wikipedia:

> From [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete):
>
> A decision problem L is **NP-complete** if it is in the set of NP problems
>   and also in the set of **NP-hard** problems.
>
> From [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard):
>
> A problem H is **NP-hard** if and only if there is an **NP-complete** problem
>   L that is polynomial time Turing-reducible to H [...].

So it appears that the definition of NP-completeness depends on the definition of NP-hardness, and vice versa.

What is going on here? How can I untangle these concepts?

Comment: Wikipedia is not always the best source. See [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/472).

Comment: That's what you get if everybody wants explanations in "plain English".